# Advantages of using a struct to return success/failure, error message and inserted ID back from a method in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

What is the best practice way to return success/failure status, any error message & perhaps an inserted ID or say a filename - when calling a method in C# (in my case an MVC 5 website).

I have been using a struct similar to this (file name is the name of the file just inserted - that could be replaced by the ID of the database record successfully inserted):

```
public struct MyResult
{
    public bool Success;
    public string Filename;
    public string ErrorMessage;
}
```

Then using MyResult as the return type for the method.

I am looking for objective advantages and disadvantages more than opinions. Or typical issues that are likely to arise from say using a struct v a class v a tuple when calling a method in this scenario.

Are there performance advantages to using a struct v a class v a tuple or a ref say (I understand the latter is generally seen as bad practice).

What is common / best practice and why?

Strangely I can find little on this anywhere.

Comment: Any hypothetical performance gain would be moot when such data needs to be transferred over the Internet.

Comment: With regards to class vs struct, here you have the official voice: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx. Check out the "consider" and "avoid" parts at the end.

Comment: @Andrew thanks I read that - it all makes sense except the conclusion rule of thumb which doesn't seem to follow the explanation at all - which implies that value types are generally more efficient. Also why should a struct only have a single value? A struct with error message, success & Id from an insert seems like a good solution as far as I can see?!

Comment: Yes, I agree, maybe that's too strict. Perhaps this is better: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/92369/172896

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several common approaches to this sort of problem. I personally favour using either enums, classes or a combination of both for this sort of result, but its a bit more complex than just that really. There is also no "right answer" - this is how I like to do things. Others may have equally good, but very different, approaches.

### Performance: Not An Issue (Probably)

You mention performance: the performance hit of doing this in any case is relatively tiny, as to be immeasurable. You gain a tonne of readability, maintainablility and clarity for a tiny tradeoff in performance. The idea behind doing this is to add extra clarity and safety: you force the programmer to consider these various states the method could return in.

And if it is too slow, then you fix it. Don't optimise too early!

### Struct or Class or Tuple

I favour classes and enums, actually.

- Classes and enums are both familiar and used universally. Struts and the like are not as familiar and might feel odd. Tuples aren't that nice in C#.
- Enums are simple and can be used to convey the state of a function, along with the data in a class.
- As I hope my explanation below will demonstrate, a class can be far more flexible, allowing more ways to do this.

### Exceptions

Firstly, let's not forget exceptions! Many would argue that an error case should trigger an exception, and they have a point: we don't want the program to continue in an erroneous state unless we have explicitly provided a way to handle it; and arguably a method should return what is says it will: if it doesn't because of some error, it's better that it blows up instead and we don't end up in a mess. Such a mechanism already exists in exceptions, so many would say: use it!

Of course, exceptions don't force the programmer to check for them (I think its a shame that C# doesn't support checked exceptions, though some would beg to differ) whereas this at least provides some level of forced awareness. Also exceptions are not always the answer, and should be reserved for truly exceptional cases - never for control logic. And sometimes it is useful to have a flag that an error did occur but we dealt with it. So this is certainly an advantage, but do consider exceptions for the reasons mentioned above.

### Enums and Classes

A word of warning: going down this path can lead to lots of over-engineering. All of this has to be a judgment on the part of the programmer: the more complex the returning data and the set of possible states we could end up in, the more engineering is warranted.

#### Simple Return States

For a simple function which either succeeds, fails or ends up in some other state where no further data or explanation is necessary, I would favour using an enum (if it is just success or failure, a bool will usually suffice):

```
public enum DeleteFileResult {
    Success, FileNotExist, MediaNotMounted
}
```

#### Optionals

If you simply return data or you don't then I recommend you use an `Optional` return parameter, borrowed from Functional programming. In Java 8, they recommend you do this instead of sentinel `null` values, and I totally agree with them - hence why I am a big fan of them in C# too! (Read about it here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html) You could consider them similar to the classes with static constructor methods I mention below, but available to be used generically everywhere.

#### Classes

I also have a habit of using a class to hold data, with an `enum` property to hold the set of states something could be in. Your example is relatively trivial and some may argue that this may be over-engineering it.

What is the point of the enum? Its just to make things clearer, really. Often, we end up in places where we return a state with multiple properties set, and a property may be set in multiple states. Consider generating a `ViewModel` for a page where the user has to have logged in - maybe we want to give away the title if the user isn't logged in, but certainly not the page content. So now its not so clear: we have to do complex logic on which properties are set and which are not to decipher the state we are in. The greater the number of properties which do that, the more complex it becomes. Yuck.

By using an enum to say what state we are in, we can switch-case between them and then use the appropriate properties. Much nicer.

An example (where it is again probably too trivial to warrant it) would be:

```
public class GetFileResult
{
    public GetFileResult(GetFileResultState state, string filename, byte[] bytes)
    {
        State = state;
        Filename = filename;
        Bytes = bytes;
        ErrorMessage = null;
    }

    public GetFileResult(string errorMessage)
    {
        State = GetFileResultState.Error;
        Filename = null;
        Bytes = null;
        ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

    public GetFileResultState State { get; }
    public string Filename { get; }
    public byte[] Bytes { get; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; }
}

public enum GetFileResultState
{
    Success, Error
}
```

In an actual codebase would consider this if there were at least four states we could end up in, in which case the extra clarity would help. We could also do this with the result:

```
var result = getFile();
switch (result)
{
    case GetFileResultSate.Success:
        // Yay!
    case GetFileResultState.Error:
        // Oh noes!
    default:
        throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

#### Most Complex Cases: Classes with Static Constructor Methods

I may even sometimes make the constructors private and use more descriptive static constructor methods, if the problem was complex enough that I felt that the extra readability would outweight the extra code - so, imagine that the code above had private constructors and I would add:

```
public static GetFileResult FileNotFound => new GetFileResult("File not found");
public static GetFileResult DiskNotMounted => new GetFileResult("Disk not mounted");
```

The you can return results like:

```
return GetFileResult.FileNotFound;
```

which is incredibly descriptive, and doesn't require you to mess around with unecessary parameters;

### Conclusion

I hope it is clear that this is a judgment. There is no "one-size-fits-all" solution. We need the right approach for the problem. Consider what I have discussed, in levels of increasing complexity:

- Exceptions
- Booleans
- Optionals
- Enums
- Classes (POCO)
- Classes with Enum States
- Classes with Enum Sates and Static Contstructor Methods

This is certainly not a definitive list. We mustn't over-engineer, but we must consider what makes it clearest for the programmer. And that judgment is up to you.

Comment: Small typo, missing 't': `GetFileResultSate.Success`.

Comment: Just a word about exceptions: try exceptions to be exactly that: exceptions. I mean, don't use those as the normal way of handling the workflow. If there is an error you expect to occur, don't throw exceptions but handle appropriately. Having a try-catch block doesn't slow down your code when no exceptions occur, but it does when there is one. So, throw one when there's something really critic that shouldn't be happening, and not for any problem faced. Remember that exceptions go across all your code structure and when used excessively they make the logic harder to understand and maintain.

Comment: Thanks Andrew - great point. I guess it all comes down to using the correct tool for the job. I would say that if the error is going to affect the rest of your program in such a way as to leave it in an invalid state, then an exception is the way to go. If you handle it internally then, why alert the rest of the world. But yes, control logic via exceptions is awful.

Comment: Side note: all this will [change in C# 7](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/347).

Comment: Thanks. So what would you do in a scenario where it was a simple insert into a sql server database - where there were multiple unique constraints on fields. How can we tell the user which unique constraint was violated in the most efficient way possible?

Comment: I did decide to simplify what my methods were trying to return and to let them fail when appropriate. thx.